# Building a scalable social media platform

Tags: open-source, social-networks

If I want to build my own scalable platform where users can do typical things like post their comments and responses, like/dislike/forward posts etc., are there any opensource solutions that I can look into?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at Mastodon and some of the other Fediverse solutions

https://joinmastodon.org/

https://fediverse.party/

Answer (score 0):

As per [Alternative Social Media: From Critique to Code](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2955827), other options include:

- diaspora
- GNU social
- Twister
- Ello
- Galaxy2
- Sone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The citation has already been included in the response.  Personally I have nothing more to add.